# Python Copying part of string

Tags: python, string, copy

I have this line

```
Server:x.x.x.x # U:100 # P:100 # Pre:0810 # Tel:xxxxxxxxxx
```

and I want to copy the value 0810 which is after Pre: value
How i can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the re module ('re' stands for regular expressions)
This solution assumes that your `Pre:` field will always have four numbers.
If the length of the number varies, you could replace the `{4}`(expect exactly 4) with `+` (expect 'one or more')

```
>>> import re
>>> x = "Server:x.x.x.x # U:100 # P:100 # Pre:0810 # Tel:xxxxxxxxxx"
>>> num = re.findall(r'Pre:(\d{4})', x)[0] # re.findall returns a list

>>> print num
'0810'
```

You can read about it here:

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 1):

As usual in these cases, the best answer depends upon how your strings will vary, and we only have one example to generalize from.

Anyway, you could use string methods like [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to get at it directly:

```
>>> s = "Server:x.x.x.x # U:100 # P:100 # Pre:0810 # Tel:xxxxxxxxxx"
>>> s.split()[6].split(":")[1]
'0810'
```

But I tend to prefer more general solutions.  For example, depending on how the format changes, something like

```
>>> d = dict(x.split(":") for x in s.split(" # "))
>>> d
{'Pre': '0810', 'P': '100', 'U': '100', 'Tel': 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'Server': 'x.x.x.x'}
```

which makes a dictionary of all the values, after which you could access any element:

```
>>> d["Pre"]
'0810'
>>> d["Server"]
'x.x.x.x'
```